# Secure way to encrypt a file that can be used on other computers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, security, encryption, hash

Lets say my program is an Anti-Virus.
Lets also say I have a file, called "Signatures.dat". It contains a list of viruses to scan. 
I would like to encrypt that file in a way that it can be opened my by anti-virus on any computer but the users wont able to see the content of that file.

How would I accomplish that task ?

I was looking at thigs like DPAPI, but I dont think that would work in my case because it's based on User's setting. I need my solution to be universal.

I've got a method to encrypt it, but then I am not sure how to store the keys.
I know that storing it in my code is really unsecure, so I am really not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: It is not possible to have a file that can be decrypted by one program but not by another if both programs run on the same machine. Solution 1: do not give the file to the user; provide some kind of web service such that at least some parts of the program do not run on the user's machine. Solution 2: do not encrypt the file, but obfuscate it enough that the user loses interest in deobfuscating it.

Answer (score 5):

You want the computers of the users to be able to read the file, and you want the computers of the users to be unable to read the file. As you see, this is a contradiction, and it cannot be solved.

What you are implementing is basically a DRM scheme. Short of using TPM (no, that doesn't work in reality, don't even think about it), you simply **cannot make it secure**. You can just use obfuscation to make it as difficult as possible to reverse-engineer it and retrieve the key. You can store parts of the key on a server and retrieve it online (basically doing what EA did with their games) etc., but you probably will only make your product difficult to use for legitimate users, and anyone who *really* wants to will still be able to get the key, and thus the file.

Answer (score 0):

In your example are you trying to verify the integrity of the file (to ensure it hasn't been modified), or hide the contents?

If you are trying to hide the contents then as has been stated ultimately you can't.

If you want to verify the file hasn't been modified than you can do this via hashes. You don't appear to have confused the two use-cases but sometimes people assume you use encryption to ensure a file hasn't been tampered with.

Your best bet might be to use both methods - encrypt the file to deter casual browsers, but know that this is not really going to deter anyone with enough time. Then verify the hash of the file with your server (use https, and ensure you validate the certificates thumbprints). This will ensure the file hasn't been modified even if someone has cracked your encryption.